# Set background color of wearable notification

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications, wear-os

I want to set the background color of a notification in a wearable device. The only method that I found is **setBackground(Bitmap background)** of **NotificationCompat.WearableExtender** but this is only for bitmaps. Is it a good idea to create a bitmap rectangle and use this as the background of my notification? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotificationCompat.Builder, in this one you can use setColor and add it to NotificationCompat.WearableExtender with the method .extend(). like this:

`NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setContentTitle("Title");
            builder.setColor(COLOR HERE);
            NotificationCompat.WearableExtender builderExtended = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
            builderExtended.extend(builder);
builder.build();`